# Сложение чисел на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли сложить два числа на jquery?

Comment: так же как в js

Comment: никак, jQuery этого не умеет

Comment: [Stack Overflow: шутки здесь неуместны](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2697)

Comment: это обратная шутка? Когда-то был анекдот в духе "Как сложить 2 числа на js" и все ответы подключить JQuery...

Comment: @pavel, не все - там был один заминусованный без jQuery :-)

Comment: @pavel http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/248633

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Jquery нету метода сложения чисел, это можно сделать на чистом js

```
var number1 = 2;
var number2 = '3';

var result = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
console.log(result);
```

Но можно пойти дальше и создать настоящий метод в Jquery для сложения чисел:

```
(function($) {
    $.sum = function() {    
        return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function (sum, current) {
            return sum + parseInt(current);
        }, 0);
    };
})(jQuery);

$.sum(1,2,3,4);
-> 10
```

Comment: [-1 not enough jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question/48195#48195)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this calculates values automatically 
  sum();
  $("#num1, #num2").on("keydown keyup", function() {
    sum();
  });
});

function sum() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
  var result1 = parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Num 1:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Num 2:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" readonly />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```